# pc powers on after screen going off

Tags: windows-10, power-management

so, i have the following configuration:

a pc with a gigabyte gtx 9xx video card, tied through hdmi to a samsung smart tv. pc is running windows 10

problem is, recently (can't figure exactly since when) the pc has a weird behavior: i power it off, then, no matter how much time passes, exactly the moment when i turn off the tv using its remote, the computer powers on

this literally happens everytime, and i haven't found any issues online related to this

Comment: if your tv is particularly power hungry and connected to the same outlet/power strip your PC is, there is the slight possibility that turning off the TV causes a power surge, or possibly even some sort of ground loop that trips your PC on. See what happens if you plug either the TV or computer into a different outlet

Comment: Does this still happen even if the HDMI cable from the computer to the TV is unplugged?

Comment: ok. so I tried decoupling the hdmi, removing some power sources, just to be safe, none of that worked. I also did a bios upgrade, which didn't help.

Comment: i was thinking it was a WOL sort of issue since it wasn't related to the video card (which was my initial impression), since I use WOL sometimes, i went looking into windows network card settings. seems there was a "wake on magic PATTERN" setting set to Enabled (besides the wake on magic PACKET" which is the WOL setting. I turned the pattern setting off and it seems not to cause the issue anymore